# Python Count how many types of characters in a file

Tags: python, file, file-io

New to python, I am writing a script that is doing a bunch of I/O stuff, one function is suppose to count how many character types which are =  [OHCN] are in a file, not how many occurrences. for examples: if a file has "OOOOOHHHHNNN" it would be 3. Here is what I have, is there a better and more efficient way of doing this? One more question, I am doing a lot of file editing in this script, initially I have a few functions that open the files that need to be modified. Would it be more efficient to handle everything in one function (so open the file once and do what I need to do in the file) or have each function open and the files and do its thing then close, then have the other function open and do that thing etc.... again thank you for any help

```
def ReadFile(xyzfile, inputFile):

     key_atoms = "OHCN"
     s =  open(xyzfile).read()

     atom_count = {ltr: 0 for ltr in key_atoms}

     for char in text:
         if char in key_atoms:
             atom_count[char] += 1
     for key in sorted(atom_count):
        with open(inputFile) as f:
             string1 = "ntyp = 2"
             string2 = "ntyp = ", atom_count[key]
             s = f.read()
             s = s.replace(str(string1), str(string2))
```

Comment: Check out `Counter` in the `collections` module in the stdlib

Comment: What is the first `s` here? I think you probably meant: `text = open(xyzfile).read()`. And always use `with` statements while handling files.

Comment: @b10n Since OP wants the count of just OHCN, I am not sure how `collections.Counter` is going to be good here.

Comment: Could you clarify? The statement *if a file has "OOOOOHHHHNNN" it would be 3* seems to contradict your code...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary my inital understanding was that OP wanted counts of OHCN in the file, counter would provide that. Upon reflection though it seems unclear. OP can you give a more detailed example of desired output?

Comment: @b10n, to be more specific, I have an .xyz file(s) (coordinates) and an input file that lets call it test.in, test.in is a template file which contains the line "ntyp = 2" (number of types of atoms). I want to create a specific input file for n amount of molecules (xyz files). I want to open an xyz file and read how many types of atoms are in the file, not occurrences the range of atoms are H N O C, and replace what is in the template file with the number that i read from the xyz file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after the unique types of each atom (or character), then we can use a `set` and find the intersection of that with the characters in a file which we can access without reading the entire file into memory (we use `itertools.chain` here instead of a nested loop). Also by using the `with` statement with both files we get an all or nothing approach (if we can't open both xyzfile and input_file - then we shouldn't bother to proceed anyway). Your current code looks like it can be reduced to:

```
from itertools import chain

with open(xyzfile) as f1, open(input_file) as f2:
    atom_count = len(set('OHCN').intersection(chain.from_iterable(f1)))
    s = f2.read().replace('ntyp = 2', 'nytp = {}'.format(atom_count))
```

Your replacement could probably be more efficient but it's not specified what `s` is being used for.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to ask, if I want to add a line for a specific character that has been called would doing something like this work using what you offered: for char in set('OHCN'): if 'H' print (#specifc line) elif 'N' print (#specific line) etc...

Comment: What you provided me was able to count the the number of types, I am trying to use that to do something like this. If the xyz file has O C H, print out O   16.000 oxgygen, print H    1.0000 hydrogen, on a different line in the input file. without creating a new function, make sense?

Comment: @octain sure... that's probably better as another question though as it's somewhat tangential to this one :)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this on my own, if I am unable to do so, I will post it up, thanks again!

Comment: @octain good luck - be interesting to see what you come up with :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61700/discussion-between-octain-and-jon-clements).

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = {}
with open(infilepath) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for char in line:
            if char not in counts:
                counts[char] = 0
            counts[char] += 1

print("There are", len(counts), "different characters in the file")
for key in counts:
    print("There are", counts[key], "occurrences of", key, "in the file")
```